# Dada una frase acabada en punto, contar cuantas palabras empiezan con la letra S

Tags: c

Muy buenas.

Compilo y todo bien, ejecuto y todo bien, el problema radica que cuando por ejemplo meto una frase donde SÍ debería contarme almenos que hay 1 palabra que empieza por S, el contador sigue en 0.

¿Alguien me echa un cable?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int cont;
    char c;

    printf ("Escribe una frase acabada en punto: ");    
    scanf ("%c", &c);

    cont = 0;

    if ((c == 's') || (c == 'S')){
        cont = 1;
    }

    while (c != '.'){
        if (c == ' '){
            scanf ("%c", &c);
            if ((c == 's') || (c == 'S')) {
                cont ++;
                scanf ("%c", &c);
            }
            else {
                scanf ("%c", &c);
            }
        scanf ("%c", &c);
        }

    }       

    printf ("Hay %d palabras que empiezan por la letra S.\n", cont);
}
```

De antemano, 
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo raro es que tu programa termine:

```
while (c != '.'){
  if (c == ' '){
    scanf ("%c", &c);
    if ((c == 's') || (c == 'S')) {
      cont ++;
      scanf ("%c", &c);
    }
    else {
      scanf ("%c", &c);
    }
    scanf ("%c", &c);
  }
}
```

Fíjate que no hay ningún `scanf` fuera del `if (c == ' ')`, luego si el carácter en cuestión **no** es un espacio el programa entrará en un bucle sin fin... no saldrá del `while` porque el carácter no es un punto y no leerá más caracteres porque el carácter **no** es un espacio.

En este contexto asumo que o bien te has equivocado al copiar el programa o bien nos estás mintiendo y el programa no te devuelve ni 0 ni 1 ni nada porque, directamente, no funciona.

Lo he puesto como respuesta pero realmente es un comentario... lo que pasa es que la web no deja poner comentarios tan largos y, además, no sería legible.

Answer (score 0):

Inicializa tu contador, es decir int cont=0;
Y prueba poniendo cont+=1; o cont=cont+1; Y deberias usar un string para la variable c y no char.

Comment: No has probado a implementar esa solución, ¿verdad? lo comento porque realmente esto dificilmente va a solucionar el problema. El programa puede funcionar perfectamente con `char`, `cont++` es preferible a `cont+=1`, y ya está inicializando `cont=0`... otra cosa es que no lo haga en la misma línea que la declaración... pero lo hace

Answer (score 0):

## El programa lo he retocado para que funcione.

Pero creo que te servira. Saludos :P

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 1000

int main (void) {
int i,j,cont;
char c[MAX],copi_min[MAX];
printf ("Escribe una frase: ");    
gets(c);

i=0;j=0;
while(c[i]!='\0')//LA convertire en minusculas para trabajar mas comodo.
{
    copi_min[j]=tolower(c[i]);//Tolower es una funcion de la blioteca ctype.h
    copi_min[j+1]='\0';     //combierte los caracteres en minusculas,solo trabaja de uno a uno.
    i++;j++;                
}

cont=0;
if(copi_min[i==0]=='s')
   {
       cont++;
   }
i=0;
while(c[i]!='\0')
{
   if(copi_min[i]==' ' && copi_min[i+1]=='s')
   {
       cont++;
   }
   i++;
}    
printf ("Hay %i palabras que empiezan por la letra S.\n",cont);
return 0;
}
```

Alguna duda comenta mela para ver si puedo responderte.